# Can I Create Amazon Connect Contact flow using Scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, scripting, amazon-connect

I know how to create amazon contact flows manually, But I want to automate this process and want to create contact flows using scripts, so is it even possible in amazon connect to create contact flows using scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The contact flows are just json files that use the contact flow language as documented here...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/flow-language.html

You can then use the CreateContactFlow and UpdateContactFlowContent API calls to programatically update the flows. This can be incorporated into CloudFormation Scripts as well to automate the whole process.

This is all very useful when migrating between dev and prod environments, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is very useful. But I can't find the proper syntax to create a yml file and configure the required blocks.
I mean, I can't find the sample yml file(JSON file).

Comment: The contact flow files are JSON not YAML. There is an example of the JSON structure [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/flow-language-example.html). This has commenting so is a good place to start.

You can also export your existing flows from the GUI to see how more complicated flows are constructed.

Comment: Thanks, @ledge. Let me go through it.